# Можно ли как-нибудь написать стили только к определенным CSS селекторам (.css файлу), если у них нет общего селектора?

Tags: css

Я дописываю стили к другому сайту. У меня свой normalize, у сайта свой (особенно проблема в свойстве box-sizing). Можно ли как-нибудь применить старый normalize ТОЛЬКО к старым стилям, а свой normalize только к новым (своим)? Кроме варианта с добавлением ко всем селекторам еще одного селектора, к которому и применяется normalize (это очень долго и муторно, да и на читабельность стилей влияет).

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что правильным вариантом будет переписать стили, чтобы не плодить костыли... Это, конечно, муторно и долго, но иначе Вы же сами окончательно можете все запутать и наплодить ошибок, которые потом не найдете. А если после Вас программист будет дорабатывать? Два файла normalize это же ад.

Answer (score 0):

Если нет ни времени, ни бюджета переписывать css - рекомендую добавить свой кастомные класс к body, и потом начать дописывать свои стили. Единственное - нужно хорошо понимать специфичность и умело пользоваться этим. Сделать то, что вы говорите вполне возможно и не так уж и сложно. Удачи вам!